# CSS: Variable size for one column in a table

Tags: html, css

I want a 100px table, with 4 columns that are each 25px.

Then when the browser is expanded, the first column can become up to 50px.

Is there a CSS only solution? I'd really like to avoid using js for setting these styles.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td>Item 1 expands</td>
   <td>Item 2</td>
   <td>Item 3</td>
   <td>Item 4</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  width: 25px;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
  ?? max-width: 500px; ??
  ?? width: 25%; ??
}
```

Comment: `min-width:25px`, `max-width:50px`, `width:25%`

Comment: Is there a particular reason the table itself is restricted to 100px wide?  If the cells are all clamped to 25px, then the table should be 100px wide by default.

Comment: I'm overriding a style that sets the `width: auto`, unfortunately I have to build on top of other peoples components for this project. Maybe I should try `width: default`?

Comment: What exactly "browser is expanded" means?

Comment: @DonnyP There's no need to override `width: auto` in this instance.  Tables want to be as small as their contents will allow them to be, and auto doesn't interfere with that in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the column expand smoothly instead of snapping into a new width with media queries:

```
table{ 
  max-width: 125px;
}
td{
   min-width: 25px;
}
td:nth-child(1){
   width:40%; // Translates to roughly 50px
}
```

This will allow the first column to expand with the available window space.

http://jsfiddle.net/RUNcm/

This works because if the table goes below `125px` in width, the `min-width` of td kicks in and keeps the first child from going below `25px`.

On the other hand, if the table is larger than `100px` in width (because the user expanded the browser window), `40%` width will allow it to go up to `52px` but no further. (that's what `max-width 125px;` helps moderate).

**Note on `nth-child`:** As Jay Na stated, `nth-child` has less browser support than `first-child`. You might want to look into using the `first-child` pseudo-class instead.

*MDN Docs*

`nth-child` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child

`first-child` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:first-child

Comment: But when the wil <tr> ever change size? It will always stay 52px in this method.

Comment: So are you not setting the table's size now? I think you should try this in fiddle :)

Comment: Great answer. Probably better to use :first-child for more browser support

Answer (score -1):

Set a with of 25px on the TD elements you want fixed. From that point, the width of the table will define the width of the first column, so you can define that however makes sense.

Edit for example:

```
table {
    max-width:575px;
}
td {
  width: 25px;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
width:auto;
}
```

Comment: I tested this and it doesn't work :( The first column stays collapsed and expands based on it's content.

Answer (score -2):

You would do it like this:

```
@media all and (min-width:400px) { /* or whatever the threshold size is */
    td:first-child {width:50px}
}
```